# How to count relations in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How can I count for example the number of roles for a user?

When I try this:

```
User::with('roles')->count();
```

it just counts the number of users.

What I need is to return the number of roles per user. For example:

```
[
   {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "user",
     "roles": 2 
   },
   {
     "id": 3,
     "name": "user",
     "roles": 1 
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent does not support this out-of-the-box.

You can read this great article on how to achieve this:

[How to get `hasMany` relation count efficiently?](http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/)

Comment: Great article indeed, this method is what I use every time I come across this

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the `$user` object, you can do the following:

```
$rolecount = $user->roles()->count();
```

Or if you are using eager loading you can drop the `(` & `)` at roles

```
$rolecount = $user->roles->count();
```

Comment: The OP has a collection of users. Doing this for each user means an extra query *for every single user*. That's terribly inefficient.